# PHP remove an element from an array with objects by property name

Tags: php

I have this json Format that is my final response, when i get it from an API it only has a property Name. I get this using json_decoe

```
apiErrors[
    {
        PropertyName: "Name1",
        DisplayName: "Name1",
        Step: "Step1
    },
        PropertyName: "Name2",
        DisplayName: "Name2",
        Step: "Step2
    }
]
```

I want to remove the items with "Step2" on the Step property.

in PHP I Iterate using a foreach and add the display and step properties

```
$apiErrors = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

foreach ($apiErrors as $value) {
    if ($value->PropertyName == "Name1") {
        $value->DisplayName = 'Name1';
        $value->Step = 'Step1';
    }
    if ($value->PropertyName == "Name2") {
        $value->DisplayName = 'Name2';
        $value->Step = 'Step2';
    }
}
```

I tried to do this

```
if (($key = array_search("Step2", $apiErrors)) !== false) {
    unset($apiErrors[$key]);
}
```

but it doesn't remove anything

Comment: Why are you adding displayname and step in your second if to begin with, if you don’t need that data? Why are you not doing the unsetting inside of that if block instead?

Comment: $key is undefined

Comment: 1. It's not JSON, 2. `json_decode($var, true)` will get you array instead of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple filtering will do the job:

```
$apiErrors = array_filter(
    $apiErrors,
    function ($v) { return 'Step2' !== $v->Step; }
);
```

Comment: I get an error saying cannot use object of type stdClass as array, before using this data, I get it from using json_decode, not sure if cause of this

Comment: Fixed the notation to `->`.

Comment: thanks this worked, I'm still new to PHP and so hard to know what I am working with cause of json_decode

Answer (score 0):

I know it's confusing at first, but PHP doesn't automatically update the value if you use [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), because it makes its own local variables. You need to specify yourself with an `&` in front of the `$value`, like this: `foreach ($apiErrors as &$value) {`. This will make sure that the value in the array actually changes.

Comment: The _value_ you are working with inside the foreach loop is only a “copy”, yes. But this doesn’t apply, when the specific array item gets accessed by its key directly.

Comment: (And one should _never_ recommend the use of references, without also mentioning how important it is to unset that reference itself after you are done with it.)